# Vue, обратится к this из калбека data() return?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue3

Как я могу обратится к функции из methods в секции data() return? Существуют ли подобные методы или хуки?

Пример:

```
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
           data: {
                tooltip: {
                 y: {
                  formatter: function (t) {
                    return getToUSD(t) + " USD"
                 }
              },
            },
          }
       },
       methods: {
        myFnc(usd) {
          return usd+ ' вызванная функция';
        },
      },
     computed: {
       getToUSD(usd) {
        return this.myFnc(usd)
    },    
   }
```

Раздел formatter - это часть библиотеки apexcharts, конкретно formatter отвечает за title при наведении мыши на график и является каллбеком, что не дает мне возможности положить в this.formatter какие либо данные через другие методы.

Метод без computed:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
       data: {
            y: {
              formatter: function (t) {
                return this.myFnc(t)
              }
            }
       }
   },
   methods: {
    myFnc(t) {
      return t + ' вызванная функция';
    },
  }    
}
```

Comment: Скорее всего, Вам нужно использовать `computed()`. data() - сделано для хранение реактивных переменных.

Comment: @Node_pro к сожалению получаю ту же ошибку `Uncaught ReferenceError: myFnc is not defined`.

Comment: добавьте исходники в вопрос

Comment: @Node_pro часть кода в вопросе аналогична реальному коду. За исключением template, в котором присутствует `<apexcharts :options="data.opt" :series="data.series"></apexcharts>`. `y: formatter` - это калбек apexcharts, который отвечает за title при наведении, принимает в себя числовое значение - сумму. У меня есть функция, которая обрабатывает эту сумму и грубо говоря возвращает вместо простого числа 5192 сумму `5 тысяч 192 доллара`.

Comment: добавьте исходники в вопрос с computed

Comment: @Node_pro обновил вопрос. Я не совсем понимаю как могу обращаться к computed методам, через this та же ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно достать вот так, добавив ключ fnc, который ссылается как раз на нужную фукнцию `fnc: this.myFnc,`:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
       data: {
            fnc: this.myFnc, // Создаем ключ со ссылкой на фукнцию
            y: {
              formatter: function (t) {
                return this.fnc(t) // Вызываем
              }
            }
       }
   },
   methods: {
    myFnc(t) {
      return t + ' вызванная функция';
    },
  }    
}
```

Comment: Сильно не пинайте, на vue не пишу, но знания js помогают. Возможно это идеалогически не правильно с точки зрения vue.js, однако работает, [Тестировал в песочнице](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-silence-3yksc6?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: Довольно странно, но конкретно с apexcharts это не сработало. Функция formatter(t) автоматически вызывается по событию наведения курсора на график для вывода значения в title. Я получаю ошибку о том, что this.d не является функцией. Хотя, попробовал использовать не для apexcharts и даже написал аналогичное действие для вывода данных функцией formatter при событии и всё работает, так же работает с выводом в vue-template, как в вашем примере, а вот с apexcharts работать не хочет.

Comment: @Fox Попробуйте заменить `formatter: function (t)` на `formatter: this.myFnc`. Вдруг получится. Возможно имеет место быть проблема с потерей контекста

Comment: К сожалению и это не сработало, возможно и есть способ, но решил не самым верным способом - перенести всю логику функции, которая форматируем мне сумму в функцию `myFnc(t)`