# Вызов функции после коллбэк

Tags: javascript, vue.js, callback

Как правильно вызвать функцию после коллбэк?

```
pay (amount) {
      const data = {
        payment: {
          amount: amount,
          description: 'Оплата',
          created_at: new Date(),
          options: {
            callbacks: {
              result_url: 'https://my-domain.com/result',
              check_url: 'https://my-domain.com/check'
            }
          }
        },
        successCallback: function (item) {
          this.create(item) //при вызове этой функции выдает ошибку, прописанную снизу
        },
        errorCallback: function (item) {
          console.log(item)
        }
      }
      // здесь функция, после завершения которой, выполняются коллбэки. Я удалила часть
    },
    create (item) {
      console.log('lll25', item)
    }
```

ОШИБКА: TypeError: this.create is not a function
at i.successCallback

а нужно чтоб при успешном выполнении оплаты, выполнялся функция create. Можете подсказать мою ошибку? Благодарю заранее

Comment: Почему возникает ошибка [this.createAPaymentHistory is not a function](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479423/). На сколько я понимаю, у вас теряется контекст при вызове функции. Проверьте, что есть this в момент вызова. Возможно функцию create надо как то отдельно передать или забиндить. Один из вариантов [вот тут описывался](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1490487/vue-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba-this-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b0-data-return/1490523#1490523) - может поможет в решении

Comment: В приведенном коде `createAPaymentHistory` нигде не вызывается

Comment: ой, я исправила. Но, все же не получается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас при вызове колбэка `successCallback` создаётся новый контекст, так как вы объявляете функцию при помощи `function`. Используйте **стрелочную** функцию для того что бы использовать внешний конекст.

```
successCallback: (item) => {
   this.create(item)
},
```

Также [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/428566/) вы можете почитать об использовании стрелочных функций.